# "mean" for consecutive rows with values bigger than x (by groups)

Tags: r, linux

This is my df (data.frame):

```
group1  group2   value
chr1     a        1 
chr1     a        1
chr1     a        1
chr1     b        2.2
chr1     b        2.5 
chr1     b        2.5
chr1     b        2.8
chr2     c        3.1
chr2     c        -3.2
chr2     c        -3.7
chr2     c        -3.1
chr2     d        4
```

For the values in column "value" belonging to the same group2 and group1, if there are more than 3 consecutive values larger than 2 or smaller than -2, mean of these values are calculated,otherwise the original values are kept.

The output should be:

```
group1  group2   value      mean
chr1     a        1          1 # does not change because it's smaller than 2
chr1     a        1          1
chr1     a        1          1
chr1     b        2.2        2.5 # mean of 2.2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.8
chr1     b        2.5        2.5 
chr1     b        2.5        2.5 
chr1     b        2.8        2.5
chr2     c        3.1        3.1 # not used for mean calculation above (different group)
chr2     c        -3.2       -3.3 # mean of -3.2, -3.7, -3.1
chr2     c        -3.7       -3.3 
chr2     c        -3.1       -3.3 
chr2     d        4          4
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How is the data expected to be read by Perl? Is it pure text, and thus need to be parsed? Or perhaps is It a matrix (array of arrays) in memory?

Comment: Sorry, first time here. thanks

Comment: I was editing it afterward while you were helping edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, create a grouping variable using `rleid` from data.table.  data.table is not otherwise used.  Then create a Mean function which uses the rules of the question.  Finally apply Mean to `value` for each component of `g`.

```
library(data.table)
g <- with(DF, rleid((value > 2) - (value < 2), group1, group2))
Mean <- function(x) if ((all(x > 2) || all(x < -2)) && length(x) >= 3) mean(x) else x
transform(DF, value2 = ave(value, g, FUN = Mean))
```

giving:

```
   group1 group2 value    value2
1    chr1      a   1.0  1.000000
2    chr1      a   1.0  1.000000
3    chr1      a   1.0  1.000000
4    chr1      b   2.2  2.500000
5    chr1      b   2.5  2.500000
6    chr1      b   2.5  2.500000
7    chr1      b   2.8  2.500000
8    chr2      c   3.1  3.100000
9    chr2      c  -3.2 -3.333333
10   chr2      c  -3.7 -3.333333
11   chr2      c  -3.1 -3.333333
12   chr2      d   4.0  4.000000
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "group1  group2   value
chr1     a        1 
chr1     a        1
chr1     a        1
chr1     b        2.2
chr1     b        2.5 
chr1     b        2.5
chr1     b        2.8
chr2     c        3.1
chr2     c        -3.2
chr2     c        -3.7
chr2     c        -3.1
chr2     d        4"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @G.Grothendieck. Could you please explain a bit about "(value > 2) - (value < 2)", if I use "larger than 0.5 or smaller than -0.5" as the cutoff in my real data, I just replace this 2 with 0.5?

Comment: That equals 1 if value > 2, -1 if value < -2 and 0 otherwise.  Yes, you can use other cutoffs such as 0.5 and -0.5.

Comment: Now this post is closed. How could I ask a further question?

Comment: Posts which do not focus on a single language are normally closed. Also questions which do not show a code attempt to solve it yourself are normally closed.  If you can address those two items you can post another question.  Also if you do not accept any answers then others may not wish to respond to your posts.

Answer (score 1):

A perl alternative that parses data (the input data is text) could be something similar to this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_name = 'test.txt';

# Read the file

open my $fh, '<', $file_name or die $!;
undef $/;
my $file = <$fh>;
close $fh;

my %hash;
while ($file =~ m/^(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)/mg) {
    next if $3 eq 'value';
    $hash{$1}{$2}{'value'} += $3;
    $hash{$1}{$2}{'count'} ++;
}

while ($file =~ m/^((\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+))/mg) {
    if ($4 eq 'value') {
        print "$1\t\tvalue2\n";
    } else {
        print "$1\t\t";
        if ($4 < -2.0 || $4 > 3.0) {
            print $hash{$2}{$3}{'value'} / $hash{$2}{$3}{'count'};
        } else {
            print $4;
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

**Test.txt content:**

```
group1  group2   value
chr1     a        1.2 
chr1     a        1
chr1     a        1
chr1     b        2.2
chr1     b        2.5 
chr1     b        2.5
chr1     b        2.8
chr2     c        3.1
chr2     c        -3.2
chr2     c        -3.7
chr2     c        -3.1
chr2     d        4
```

**Result:**

```
group1  group2   value          value2
chr1     a        1.2           1.2
chr1     a        1             1
chr1     a        1             1
chr1     b        2.2           2.2
chr1     b        2.5           2.5
chr1     b        2.5           2.5
chr1     b        2.8           2.8
chr2     c        3.1           -1.725
chr2     c        -3.2          -1.725
chr2     c        -3.7          -1.725
chr2     c        -3.1          -1.725
chr2     d        4             4
```

Comment: `$file` should have the content of the file, not the filename. You should open a the file and use its file handle to read its content with the diamon `<$some_file_handle>` operator

Comment: @Jane, I changed my answer to read the data from a file